# React inline conditional component attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I've been searching everywhere and can't find an answer to my question. So I want a conditional attribute which is only displayed on certain conditions, example:

```
<Button {this.state.view === 'default' && 'active'}></Button>
```

As you can see I only want to indicate the button *active* if the `this.state.view` is equal to default. However, I get `Unexpected token, error...`

But when I try to put an attribute before it, for example:

```
<Button isActive={this.state.view === 'default' && 'active'}></Button>
```

It passes the syntax error and displays fine but this is not what I wanted to achieve.

How can I fix this? And what could be the reason behind it not passing?

### UPDATE

So I just found out that in `react-bootstrap` the property `active` is a shorthand of `active=true` so I solved it using

```
<Button active={this.state.view === 'default'}></Button>
```

So In case, someone encounters this problem I'm leaving it here. However, I still want to know why the conditional attribute is failing without enclosing it inside a prop-like syntax, example:

This:

```
active={this.state.view === 'default'}
```

Versus

```
{this.state.view === 'default' && 'active'}
```

Comment: I posted an answer. But I think I misundertood. What do you mean by *indicate the button active*? you mean styling? or an custom `active` attribute (AFAIK there is no native html active atrribute, but `disabled`)?

Comment: @mrlew an **active** attribute. I actually solved it and posted an update but I'm still wondering the difference between the 2 syntax. It would have been easier just to print `active` inside the component versus `active=true`

Comment: I got your point. Just replaced my answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First of all, JSX is just a *syntactic sugar* for [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement). So, **it may look like**, but, in reality, **you don't specify `html attributes`**: in fact, you are always passing `props`.

For instance, the JSX code `<input type="button" value="My button" />` is transpiled into `React.createElement('input',{type:'button',value:'My Button'})`. And, when necessary, React engine renders this `React Element`  to the DOM as a HTML element.

That said, we have that JSX transpiles a `prop` without a value as **true** (check [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-default-to-true)). For instance: `<Button active></Button>` is transpiled to `React.createElement(Button, { active: true });`.

But, we know that HTML5 specification **does not accept** `attribute=true` (as pointed [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes)). For instance: `<button disabled=true></button>` is invalid. The correct is `<button disabled></button>`.

So, to render the HTML element to the DOM, React considers only `props` that are valid `attributes` (if not, the attribute is not rendered). Check [all supported html attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes). And, then, finally, if it's a boolean attribute, it removes the *true*/*false* value, rendering it properly.

For instance: `<button active={true}></button>` is transpiled to `React.createElement("button", { active: true });` and then React renders to the DOM `<button></button>`, because there is no `active` attribute in HTML specification for the `<button/>` tag (is not in the supported attributes list).

But `<button disabled={true}></button>` is transpiled to `React.createElement("button", { disabled: true });` and React renders to the DOM `<button disabled></button>`.

I just said that to clarify your case.

You're trying to pass an `active` prop to the `Button` component (first letter uppercase means that's a React component: there is a React Component called `Button` handled somewhere in your code).

That means:

`<Button active></Button>` is transpiled to `React.createElement(Button, { active: true });`

and

`<Button active={true}></Button>` is transpiled to `React.createElement(Button, { active: true });`

**The same thing!**

So, if you want to do a conditional `prop`, you can simply do something like that:

```
<Button active={this.state.view === 'default'}></Button>
```

You have a condition inside brackets. Means that, if your `this.state.view` is equal to `default` (true), `active` prop will be passwed down to the component with the `true` value. If not equal, with the `false` value.

`Button` Component, then, must someway handle this `active` prop. It can render the `button` element and, for instance, change it's style, pass the `disabled` prop... I created a fiddle to demonstrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/5rsx40gu/

Answer (score 18):

Actually, I guess it is a duplicated question that I answered it in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53784006/6877799) sometimes ago. for this specific post, there is no need condition prop for a boolean value, because it works well like below:

```
const { booleanValue } = this.props;
return (
    <input checked={booleanValue} />
);
```

Or make your own boolean value:

```
const booleanValue = someThing === someOtherThing;
return (
    <input checked={booleanValue} />
);
```

Both of them work well, because when the `booleanValue` is `false`, `react` doesn't see the `active` prop, hence it does not exist, unless you pass `checked` prop to a specific component that the component will receive false checked prop from `this.props`.

**But**, if you wanna a have a prop on your specific component with a condition and if the condition returns false you don't want it there are two ways, I like second:

First:

```
<Component someProp={condition ? yourValue : undefined} />
```

Second:

```
<Component {...(condition && { someProp: yourValue })} />
```

Answer (score 3):

In JSX, component properties (or props) compile to a plain JavaScript object. Prop names are used as the keys of the object, and prop values are stored under those keys. [The first example from the JSX docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) does a great good job demonstrating this. In your case `{view === 'default' && true}` is a raw value without an associated prop name. Without a prop name to use as a key (specified by the syntax `name=`), JSX has nowhere to put that value in the final props object.

However, JSX will accept props via your original syntax if the expression inside the curly braces evaluates to an object. For example, you could do `{{ active: view === "default" }}`. In this case JSX can get both the key and value that it needs from the provided object, so no `active=` is necessary.