# skip passing props in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to not to pass props base on condition? I can do this

```
const condition = true
<ThirdPartyComponent custom={() => condition ? <h1>hello<h1> : null}
```

but ThirdPartyComponent will still get null, I want to skip passing custom prop to ThirdPartyComponent. Note that I don't have access to ThirdPartyComponent.

Comment: Try using `undefined` instead of `null`. As per the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232659/react-inline-conditionally-pass-prop-to-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render component on basis of condition. Using ternary operator, if true then pass prop or don't pass it on else condition

You can do like this -

```
const condition = true;
condition ? (<ThirdPartyComponent custom={value} />) : (<ThirdPartyComponent /> )
```