# How to use Platform.OS to elements in react native?

Tags: react-native, platform

I want to use just KeyboardAwareScrollView without any functions on IOS and given below code for android.

> I know that I need to use Platform.OS === 'ios' ? :
>
> BUT I DON'T UNDERSTAND HOW TO REALISE IT. Please help me

```
render(){
 return(

    <KeyboardAwareScrollView
       extraScrollHeight={100}
       enableOnAndroid={true}
       keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
    >
      <TextInput
        style={styles.inputContainerStyle}
        label="Username"
        value={this.state.username}
        onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}
      />
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
   )
}
```

> What I've tried below: (But it doesn't work)

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
      Platform.OS === 'android' ? 
      (
         extraScrollHeight={100}
         enableOnAndroid={true}
         keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
      ) : null
  >
```

Comment: You can get your answer here [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232659/react-inline-conditionally-pass-prop-to-component)

Answer (score 42):

You can also check via node but react-native provides some ways to check platform.

**This one is recommended**

```
 import {Platform} from 'react-native';
    st styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        ...Platform.select({
          ios: {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
          },
          android: {
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
          },
        }),
      },
    });
```

**You can also use ternary expressions**

```
 import {Platform, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 200 : 100,
});
```

[Read this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code)

Answer (score 12):

You can use JSX prop spread and a ternary expression at the same time:

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
  {
    ...(Platform.OS === 'android' ? 
    { 
      extraScrollHeight={100}
      enableOnAndroid={true}
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
    } : {})
  }
>
```

I highly recommend against doing this all inline though, since it's hard to read. You could do something a bit readable (and declarative) using `Platform.select`:

```
const keyboardProps = Platform.select({
  android: { … },
  ios: {},
});
…
<KeyboardAwareScrollView {...keyboardProps}>
```

Comment: Where I should add **const keyboardProps** ? before class declared? inside class? or inside return statement?

Comment: first code can't read height 100, https://snack.expo.io/Hkd-9MkEQ, you can check here

Comment: @JustAhead You need to add the opening tag.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep your code much simpler and cleaner to understand, do this:
For example, if you want to specific "marginTop" per specific operating System. You can do this:

```
 <View style={{justifyContent:'center',marginTop:Platform.select({
            ios: '30%', //30 percent of margin is applied to IOS
            android:'10%', // 30 percent of margin is applied to Andriod

          })}}>
```

Go to this website by React-native: https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one,

```
renderKeyboardAwareScrollView(){
  if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){
    return (
       <KeyboardAwareScrollView
       extraScrollHeight={100}
       enableOnAndroid={true}
       keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
    >
      <TextInput
        style={styles.inputContainerStyle}
        label="Username"
        value={this.state.username}
        onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}
      />
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <TextInput
        style={styles.inputContainerStyle}
        label="Username"
        value={this.state.username}
        onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}
      />
    )
  }
}
render(){
 return(
  {this.renderKeyboardAwareScrollView()}
 )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This syntax works for me:

```
 keyboardProps = Platform.select({
    android: {
      enabled: true,
      keyboardVerticalOffset: 0
    },
    ios: {
      enabled: true,
      keyboardVerticalOffset: 64,
      behavior: 'height',
    },
  });

  render = () => (

    <KeyboardAvoidingView 
      {...this.keyboardProps}
    >
```

Answer (score 1):

use bracket `{}` for `Ternary Condition` inside `return ()`

so your code looks like :

```
render(){
 return(
 <View>
 { ...Platform.OS === 'android' 
    ? //if true
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView
       extraScrollHeight={100}
       enableOnAndroid={true}
       keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
    />
    : //if false
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView
      //your props for else condition
    />
    // or add null if you don't want to add another
 }
      <TextInput
        style={styles.inputContainerStyle}
        label="Username"
        value={this.state.username}
        onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}
      />
  </View>
   )
}
```

***EDITED:***

add `spread notation`(...) to make it work at `Platform.OS`

Prove:

[image: code]

[image: screen]

Comment: can you check, please, it says unterminated JSX contents https://snack.expo.io/HJWSdM1NQ

Comment: @JustAhead if you dont need to handle the iOS `KeyboardAwareScrollView` just use `null` https://snack.expo.io/Bked2KMkNQ

Comment: @JustAhead here's a [fixing](https://snack.expo.io/HkoFiMJE7), you cant put the `closed tag` of component outside `{}`

Comment: @flix Huh, you're right, it does work. Seems like Babel is cloning the element, but it's incredibly hard to read IMO. But your first example doesn't work. You can't have adjacent tags after the ternary, Babel cannot parse it.

Comment: @Li357 I'm not aware of the code, i just add my code from existing code, but you're right, the 3rd line from bottom (`</KeyboardAwareScrollView>`) should be deleted to make it work,

Comment: The text input right after is also invalid syntax. You'd have to wrap them in a container, or use keys/fragments.

Comment: @Li357 again, i'm too lazy to test the code, now i think i'm done to edit the answer

Comment: This will not work with nested components cos the top level should be closed

Answer (score 0):

In order to add keyboard awareness to iOS part of react native app just add

```
  pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
```

in podfile and run pod install inside ios folder. It will enable IQkeyboard in your iOS app and will save you from hasle.

Gotcha: You might have to re add the pod file if some how your ios project is reset.