# Change screens depending on the OS with React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I'm developing an app the uses Health Kit and Google fit, I have a screen that asks for the user's permission to track the data, how can I make the system differ from Android and iOS to send the user to the correct page?

Comment: is this post helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436886/how-to-use-platform-os-to-elements-in-react-native ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Platform.OS to elements in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436886/how-to-use-platform-os-to-elements-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

You can use property of Platform.OS and do your changes according to that. For example

`color:Platform.OS === 'ios'? 'red':'yellow'`.