# Add/Specify prop conditionally in a child component if a parent prop exists

Tags: reactjs

In a child component, I need to only specify a prop given a condition in the parent props, otherwise **don't** specify anything at all. The following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77532983/1005607) isn't good for me because I don't want to pass `undefined`. Rather, I want to avoid creating the prop at all. All other props should be undisturbed.

In this example, do not create a `value` prop if `props.value` doesn't exist.

```
        <Select id={props.dropDownName} 
                name={props.dropDownName} 
                value={props.value} /* Only if props.value exists, do not even create this prop otherwise */ 
                /* etc. */
        </Select>
```

Somehow I couldn't find a good answer even though many answers are available. Many are for older non-functional components.

Comment: This seems a bit like an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). I'd be interested to hear your reasoning for this being necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

render the whole Select component conditionally

`props.value ? <Select {...otherProps} value={props.value}/> : <Select {...otherProps} />`

I don't think there's other way to do it

Comment: Yes, that's what I settled on as well. Thanks